# ASP.NET MVC common part of page, how to make better

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

For example, many pages on the project have similar part, which requires to get data from controller.

We can create Partial View for it:

View Model class:

```
    public class DriverProfilerSidebarVM
    {
        public DriverProfilerSidebarVM()
        {
            Trucks = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Trailers = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Truck")]
        public int? TruckId { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Trucks { get; set; }
....
```

_ProfilerSidebar.cshtml:

```
@model Web.ViewModels.DriverProfilerSidebarVM
<div class="profile-sidebar">
    <div class="portlet light profile-sidebar-portlet ">

            <div class="profile-userpic">
                <img src=@(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AvatarUrl) ? Model.AvatarUrl : "/Images/coloricons/Driver-100.png") class="img-responsive" alt="Avatar Photo">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-usertitle">
                <div class="profile-usertitle-name"> @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName </div><br />
                <div class="profile-usertitle-name">@Model.Nickname</div>
            </div>

            <div class="profile-usermenu">
                <ul class="nav-item  nav page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">
                    <li id="liProfile" class="active">
                        <a class="" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Drivers",new { Model.Id })">
                            <i class="icon-user"></i> Driver Profile
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Then to use it we can select 2 ways:

1. Create controller method and call it from page:

   @Html.Action("_ProfilerSidebar", "Drivers", new { id = Model.Id }

and method:

```
    public ActionResult _ProfilerSidebar(int id, bool isEditTruckTrailer = false)
    {
        DriverProfilerSidebarVM model = ProfilerSidebar(id, isEditTruckTrailer);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

2. Add property with type DriverProfilerSidebarVM to model to each page, which uses this part and render it:

   @Html.Partial("_ProfilerSidebar", Model.ProfilerSidebar)

Both ways work. Which pros and cons for both?

Comment: The answer to this will depend greatly on the proper OO design for your classes.  Is it that X _has a_ Y or that X _is a_ Y.  If you follow the OO well then pieces will start to fall in to place.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to render the partial in `_layout`. If you're rendering user related data this can be achieve with a claims extension as the example below shows. I'd vote for this method as all the code is contained in one place, you don't need to add additional properties to your viewmodels and no one needs to remember to add html helpers to your views to render the partial. It's a little more code up front but much more maintainable. Here's an example to render a partial view inside the navbar that contains a user's name and role if they are logged in- however this could be modified to do or be about anything:

_layout.cshtml (which calls `_LoginPartial` which is the partial which relates to your example/question):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  @Styles.Render("~/content/layout")
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          @Html.ActionLink("Controller", "SomeAction", "My Link To Something")
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    @RenderBody()
  </div>

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/layout")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Then in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@using MyProject.Extensions

@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  var userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
}

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">@Html.Raw("Hello " + User.GetFullNameAndRole() + "!") <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Account", "Manage", "Account", new { userName = User.Identity.GetUserName() }, null)</li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log Off</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
}
else
{
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
  </ul>
}
```

and `User.GetFullNameAndRole()` works because of the following:

`ClaimsExtensions.cs`:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Extension class to handle adding claims to a user
  /// </summary>
  public static class ClaimsExtensions
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the full name and role of a user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetFullNameAndRole(this IPrincipal user)
    {
      var fullNameAndRoleClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity).FindFirst("FullNameAndRole");
      if (fullNameAndRoleClaim != null)
      {
        return fullNameAndRoleClaim.Value;
      }

      // If we don't find the claim for the user's full name and email for some reason, use the email address as a fall back
      return user.Identity.Name;
    }
  }
```

and in `ApplicationUser.cs`, we add a claim to the user as follows:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
      // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
      var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

      // Add custom user claims here

      // Ability to retrieve first/last name and role via the Identity class. This is so _LoginPartial.cshtml can display first name + last name 
      // and role instead of e-mail address. The other option is to create an instance of usermanager in razor in _LoginPartial.cshtml. Ew. 
      // We retrieve this custom user claim via the extension method 'GetUserNameAndRole' in ClaimsExtensions.cs
      var userRole = manager.GetRoles(userIdentity.GetUserId()).FirstOrDefault();
      var nameAndRole = string.Empty;

      if (userRole != null)
      {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName))
        {
          nameAndRole = string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", this.FirstName, this.LastName, userRole);
        }
        else
        {
          nameAndRole = string.Format("{0} ({1})", this.Email, userRole);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName))
        {
          nameAndRole = string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
        }
        else
        {
          nameAndRole = string.Format("{0}", this.Email);
        }
      }

      userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullNameAndRole", nameAndRole));

      return userIdentity;
    }
```

Comment: I know about claims, but it's useful when all pages require it. In my case I need only 10 pages, for example.